# How to get current location when app launch?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-fragmentactivity, currentlocation

In this case the map appears on the application that I'm trying to make, but when the application is opened folder appears not in the current location but in Sout Atlantic Ocean. Is there a way to bring up the current location at the time the application is opened?

**Here is my code :**

```
public class GmapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
        LocationListener
{

    GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gmaps, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        Location location;

        if(network_enabled){

            location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(location!=null){
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(-7.0559935,110.4320226))
                        .title("Kos Munyiq"));

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(-7.0500666,110.4264657))
                        .title("Kos Pos"));


                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(0));
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }
}
```

Sorry if there is something wrong with my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding marker in someplace. Try use the following code instead of those markers..

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); <<this is the main line
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("It's Me!"));
   }
});
```

The on location change functionality will give you your position even if you change your location... If you just need your current position, static, you will just need the following code,

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                    .title("It's Me!"));
```

Then you will want to animate the camera, zoom in/zoom out a little bit. 
Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, I've tried to change the code corresponding explanation. map appeared but still in South Antlantic Ocean and the current location button disappears. Is there something wrong with what I did?